# Simple Hypervisor for one OS from boot

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, virtual-machines, hypervisor

I would like to run a hypervisor that will let me install a VM on it where the end result would be such as that when these workstations will be turned on the following will happen:

- Hypervisor boots
- Virtual Machine boots
- Console of the VM is displayed to user
- User logs in to VM and works normally
- User is unable to exit the VM console view
- If user shuts down VM, hypervisor also shuts down
- If user reboots VM, only VM reboots (optional)

Is there a solution free or paid that would allow me to do this?

The user OS is Windows, the host OS can be anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I will remove the bounty, as software recommandation is offtopic on SF. Sorry for the late comment, I didn't seen your post until today. I would had move your question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but it's too old to migrate, as such I recommand you to ask there for that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, each and every HV boots a guest to the console. Usualy its the priviledged guest 0, aka "host os". It's not possible to *boot* directly to a guest, as the controling OS has to be up to present the virtual hardware to the guest.

But there is a "kiosk" mode for vmware workstation, that wouldn't let you exit the guest os. You would have to set up the host to just autostart it and nobody would notice anything.

Just google "workstation kiosk mode" to get the configuration (ACE) details. Maybe this is even possible with vmware player, bu I am not sure about that.